# MGCA technique for speech features extraction shows this error (IndexError: list index out of range)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, speech-recognition, feature-extraction

> By executing this program for speech features extraction from wav file
>   , i got problem in code ,error say IndexError: list index out of range
>
> File
>   "C:/Users/KALEEM/PycharmProjects/Speech_Processing/2-Speech_Signal_Processing_and_Classification-master/feature_extraction_techniques/mgca.py",
>   line 77, in 
>       mel_Generalized()   File "C:/Users/KALEEM/PycharmProjects/Speech_Processing/2-Speech_Signal_Processing_and_Classification-master/feature_extraction_techniques/mgca.py",
>   line 74, in mel_Generalized
>       mgca_feature_extraction(wav)   File "C:/Users/KALEEM/PycharmProjects/Speech_Processing/2-Speech_Signal_Processing_and_Classification-master/feature_extraction_techniques/mgca.py",
>   line 66, in mgca_feature_extraction
>       writeFeatures(mgca_features,wav)   File "C:/Users/KALEEM/PycharmProjects/Speech_Processing/2-Speech_Signal_Processing_and_Classification-master/feature_extraction_techniques/mgca.py",
>   line 46, in writeFeatures
>       wav = makeFormat(wav)   File "C:/Users/KALEEM/PycharmProjects/Speech_Processing/2-Speech_Signal_Processing_and_Classification-master/feature_extraction_techniques/mgca.py",
>   line 53, in makeFormat
>       wav = wav.split('/')[1].split('-')[1] IndexError: list index out of range
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

```
#!usr/bin/python
from pysptk import *
from scipy import hamming
import numpy.matlib
import scipy
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import numpy as np
import wave
from python_speech_features.sigproc import *
from math import *
from six.moves import input as raw_input


def readWavFile(wav):
        #given a path from the keyboard to read a .wav file
        #wav = raw_input('Give me the path of the .wav file you want to read: ')
        inputWav = 'C:/Users/KALEEM/PycharmProjects/Speech_Processing/2-Speech_Signal_Processing_and_Classification-master/feature_extraction_techniques'+wav
        return inputWav
#reading the .wav file (signal file) and extract the information we need
def initialize(inputWav):
        rate , signal  = wav.read(readWavFile(inputWav)) # returns a wave_read object , rate: sampling frequency
        sig = wave.open(readWavFile(inputWav))
        # signal is the numpy 2D array with the date of the .wav file
        # len(signal) number of samples
        sampwidth = sig.getsampwidth()
        print ('The sample rate of the audio is: ',rate)
        print ('Sampwidth: ',sampwidth)
        return signal ,  rate
#implementation of the low-pass filter
def lowPassFilter(signal, coeff=0.97):
        return np.append(signal[0], signal[1:] - coeff * signal[:-1]) #y[n] = x[n] - a*x[n-1] , a = 0.97 , a>0 for low-pass filters
def preEmphasis(wav):
        #taking the signal
        signal , rate = initialize(wav)
        #Pre-emphasis Stage
        preEmphasis = 0.97
        emphasizedSignal = lowPassFilter(signal)
        Time=np.linspace(0, len(signal)/rate, num=len(signal))
        EmphasizedTime=np.linspace(0, len(emphasizedSignal)/rate, num=len(emphasizedSignal))
        return emphasizedSignal, signal , rate

def writeFeatures(mgca_features,wav):
        #write in a txt file the output vectors of every sample
        f = open('mel_generalized_features.txt','a')#sample ID
        #f = open('mfcc_featuresLR.txt','a')#only to initiate the input for the ROC curve
        wav = makeFormat(wav)
        np.savetxt(f,mgca_features,newline=",")
        f.write(wav)
        f.write('\n')

def makeFormat(wav):
        #if i want to keep only the gender (male,female)
        wav = wav.split('/')[1].split('-')[1]
        #only to make the format for Logistic Regression
        if (wav=='Female'):
                wav='1'
        else:
                wav='0'
        return wav
def mgca_feature_extraction(wav):
        #I pre-emphasized the signal with a low pass filter
        emphasizedSignal,signal,rate = preEmphasis(wav)
        #and now I have the signal windowed
        emphasizedSignal*=np.hamming(len(emphasizedSignal))
        mgca_features = 'mgcep(emphasizedSignal,order=12)'
        writeFeatures(mgca_features,wav)
def mel_Generalized():
        folder = raw_input('Give the name of the folder that you want to read data: ')
        amount = raw_input('Give the number of samples in the specific folder: ')
        for x in range(1,int(amount)+1):
                wav = '/'+folder+'/'+str(x)+'.wav'
                print (wav)

        mgca_feature_extraction(wav)

#def main():
mel_Generalized()
#main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely due to unexpected input, which would be difficult for us to test.

More specifically, in the code below:

```
def makeFormat(wav):
    #if i want to keep only the gender (male,female)
    wav = wav.split('/')[1].split('-')[1]
    #only to make the format for Logistic Regression
    if (wav=='Female'):
            wav='1'
    else:
            wav='0'
    return wav
```

I would assume that `wav` is a `str`-like object (or anyway something that supports `.split()`). The result of split is generally an `Iterable`, for example a `list`. If such `Iterable` has 0 or 1 elements, trying to access its second element (using `[1]`) would raise the `IndexError: list index out of range` you are getting.
In your case, `wav` does not contain enough `/` (at least 1), enough `-` (also at least 1), or both.

Comment: Sir  in my case  input is  5 files of wav , (  .wav  16000Hz ) audio files . Need to extract features , So what can be possible solution according to this code , please suggest me

Comment: Your code is getting stuck much earlier, when it is trying to get information from the filenames.

Comment: BTW, following your code, I think it looks like the second `.split()` is failing ( i.e. `split('-')` since the other one would not fail by *construction* from line `wav = '/'+folder+'/'+str(x)+'.wav'`), so you should have a `folder` with a `-` in it, and I would expect that some of your input folder contain the word `Female` after the `-` character.

Comment: i have tested  like this   ,,,  My wav files path folder  contains 5 wav file , i rename them as  (  -female1 , -female2 , -female3  -female4 -female5 ) , and execute program now abover error resolved but it says that no such files found in directory , also i changed   Female-1 , Female-2  Female-3 Female-4 Female-5 and again No directory found , Can you please write one example for me that how my samples name should be in folder . Lot of thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a sensible way how to proceed. (1) you are getting a different error, which means that what you should ask a different question as the original one is likely to have been solved (2) you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people can understand your problem and it does not get to be a waste of everyone's time.